# Is there a simple way to reduce this set of tuples in Python

Tags: python-3.x, set, reduction

In a set of tuples (pairs), like this one:

```
s = {(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), ('v', 'n'), ('v', 'k')}
```

I would like to remove all pairs (a, b) and (a, c), so that the resulting set is:

```
{(3, 4)}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish that?

Comment: What if there are tuples `(a, b)`, `(a, c)` and `(a, d)`? Remove all? Remove only a pair? If so, which pair?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen *(a, b) and (a, c)* is a shorthand for pairs p0 and p1, where p0[0] == p1[0]. Remove all as shown in my example.

Comment: So: remove all tuples for which the first element occurs more than once as a first element in the set?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a comprehension:

```
{x for x in s if len([a for a in s - {x} if a[0]==x[0]]) == 0}
```

Basically keeping only elements `x` of `s` where the first member of `x` isn't found in `s - {x}` (s without x)

This also can be written as:

```
{x for x in s if not [a for a in s - {x} if a[0]==x[0]]}
```

Edit: you can even improve speed if `s` has a lot of element with `any`:

```
{x for x in s if not any(a[0]==x[0] for a in s - {x})}
```

Output:

```
{(3, 4)}
```